# Upgrading really old CakePHP site

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I had to migrate a client's websites over to a new server since the old server crashed.

One of the sites is based on a really old version of CakePHP.  The new server is using PHP 7.  The CakePhp site is dead in the water, using a lot PHP features that have been phased out (such as using & as a reference marker).

Source code tags seems to indicate around 2008.  There is absolutely nothing in there that relates to composer.

I have minimal experience with CakePHP.  In fact, I'm not sure where the site specific code and data would be.

**How can I update this site to a modern CakePHP site or at least something that works under PHP 7?**

Other than line by line editing in just about every file in framework, one approach, I'm thinking about is creating a completely new CakePHP site and moving the site specific files over to that.  But, then, I would like to know where or how to find the site specific files?

If it helps, here if the file header of app\webroot\index.php:

```
/* SVN FILE: $Id: index.php 7296 2008-06-27 09:09:03Z gwoo $ */
/**
 * Short description for file.
 *
 * Long description for file
 *
 * PHP versions 4 and 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) :  Rapid Development Framework <http://www.cakephp.org/>
 * Copyright 2005-2008, Cake Software Foundation, Inc.
 *                              1785 E. Sahara Avenue, Suite 490-204
 *                              Las Vegas, Nevada 89104
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @filesource
 * @copyright       Copyright 2005-2008, Cake Software Foundation, Inc.
 * @link                http://www.cakefoundation.org/projects/info/cakephp CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package         cake
 * @subpackage      cake.app.webroot
 * @since           CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @version         $Revision: 7296 $
 * @modifiedby      $LastChangedBy: gwoo $
 * @lastmodified    $Date: 2008-06-27 02:09:03 -0700 (Fri, 27 Jun 2008) $
 * @license         http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php The MIT License
 */
```

Comment: You update it by going through it file by file and rewriting whatever is needed. There is no magic wand that would do it for you. Optimally you'd make unit tests to confirm that the rewrite works as intended.

Comment: That's the approach I started on and still working on.  But it's like I'm re-writing the entire framework.  Seems like every file/  If there is an easier way, I'm all for it.

Comment: I would suggest taking the site's objective and rewrite it using CakePHP 3. There is no sense to update that old a version of CakePHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP, like most frameworks, keeps it's standard files mostly separate from site specific code.  Took me a little bit of time, but most of the site specific code will be placed in the

```
\app
```

directory.  The core framework code will reside in the other directories

So, the process of updating a site like this, would be:

1. Create a new site using PHP composer
2. Configure as necessary
3. Copy the files from old \app directory to the new \app directory.  Don't just blindly copy, but see if it's safe and there are no conflicts.  If conflicts, resolve as needed
4. Test, Fix, Test,  ...

In my case, I still needed to 'modernize' a lot of code in the \app directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to trying re-write the framework code you could run an old version of PHP (http://php.net/releases/) from the CGI-BIN of the server just for this site.

Be aware that there are some security implications: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php

This could get the site running while you seek the appropriate action, ie. rebuilding the site completely, or getting compensated appropriately for the intensive work required.

Comment: This is indeed an option as a temporary workaround.  But this would be somewhat of a last resort, as there are other sites on the server and I'd rather avoid the security issues.

Comment: It appears you should be able to find the cake version here: /path/to/cake/lib/Cake/VERSION.txt

Comment: Then you might be able to use the documentation here, to automate the process a bit: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/upgrade-shell.html and http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/upgrade-tool.html

Comment: Thanks for the efforts.  The provided links won't work in my case, as this version, is even too old for the console approach.  I've got the site somewhat working now.